# Twig: use raw filter on form_widget attr

Tags: twig, symfony

is it possible to use raw filter on form element attributes? I want something like:

```
{{ form_widget(searchForm.query, {
    'type': 'search',
    'attr': {
        'placeholder': 'Search query&hellip;'
    }
} ) }}
```

but this outputs "Search query&hellip;" into HTML
I've tried

```
'placeholder': 'Search query&hellip;'|raw
```

but it still escapes &, outputting "Search query&hellip;" again.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not put the unescaped value in the attributes?

Comment: because I don't like having special characters in source code, does not seem very clean to me...

Comment: Define "special" character. It's part of the Unicode alphabet, your source code probably is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: I use them all the time in my source code…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/filter.html) tag like this:

```
{% filter format('&hellip;')|raw %}
{{ form_widget(searchForm.query, {
    'type': 'search',
    'attr': {
        'placeholder': 'Search query%s'
    }
} ) }}    
{% endfilter %}
```

with `%s` instead of `&hellip;` in the value of placeholder

if you don't want use `%s` you can use `replace` instead of `format` with your own value (`foo` for example) :

```
{% filter replace({'foo': '&hellip;'})|raw %}
{{ form_widget(searchForm.query, {
    'type': 'search',
    'attr': {
        'placeholder': 'Search queryfoo'
    }
} ) }}
{% endfilter %}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with `&#133;` instead of `&hellip;`...